# The resul.html loads with no error but the function merge in merge.py is not executing

Tags: python, django

I want to call the merge function in the file `merge.py` when a user has entered his input in the create_proposal.html.
my `merge.py` file looks like:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from mailmerge import MailMerge

def merge(name, refer):
    template = 'template.docx'
    document = MailMerge(template)

    document.merge(
        reference = refer
    )
    print('merge')
    document.write(name)
```

And my views.py file looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import createNewFinancial
from .merge import merge

def inputPage(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =createNewFinancial(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            reference = form.cleaned_data['reference']

            merge(name, reference)

    form = createNewFinancial()
    return render(request, 'create_proposal.html', {'form': form})

def resultPage(request):
    return render(request, 'result.html')
```

the template create_proposal.html looks like:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-left: 10vw;">
            <h2>New Financial Proposal</h2>
            <form class="form-group" action="result/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
                {{form}}<br><br>
                <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

I am trying to create a word document with file name from user input in `create_proposal.html`and also  merge the reference number from user input in the template using `mailmerge`

Comment: And what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: It is not inserting the reference number in the template. It shows the result page but with no error but the function merge is not being executed

Comment: Please edit your question with a complete description of the problem, it will be better to find it there than in the comments.

Comment: But you do not do anything with the result of `document`. You construct one in `merge(..)`, but then you basically "throw it away".

Comment: no it's supposed to write a new document with the name provided. It actually works when I execute it from the command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my problem,
I was trying to call my function inside the inputPage fuction when I should have put it in the resultPage function.

so the views.py file should look like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import createNewFinancial
from .merge import merge

def inputPage(request):


    form = createNewFinancial()
    return render(request, 'create_proposal.html', {'form': form})

def resultPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form =createNewFinancial(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            reference = form.cleaned_data['reference']
            print(name)

            merge(name, reference)

    return render(request, 'result.html')
```